# Nodejs) express deprecated req.param(name) - Expresss 4.13 version

Tags: node.js, parsing, express

> This code is to send data using post form,save data and list elements
>   on page.

First of all, The function features if database has data, it can render to other view template.[user.js]

```
var addstat = function(req, res) {
console.log('stat 모듈 안에 있는 addstat 호출됨.');

var database = req.app.get('database');

var paramid = req.param('id');
var paramround = req.param('round');
var paramgroup = req.param('group');

//var paramhomeImage = req.param('homeImage');
var paramhomeName = req.param('homeName');
var paramhomeScore = req.param('homeScore');
var paramhomeTotalShoot = req.param('homeTotalShoot');
var paramhomeValShoot = req.param('homeValShoot');
var paramhomeTotalpass = req.param('homeTotalpass');
var paramhomeValpass = req.param('homeValpass');
var paramhomeOffside = req.param('homeOffside');
var paramhomeCornerkick = req.param('homeCornerkick');
var paramhomeFoul = req.param('homeFoul');

//var paramawayImage = req.param('awayImage');
var paramawayName = req.param('awayName');
var paramawayScore = req.param('awayScore');
var paramawayTotalShoot = req.param('awayTotalShoot');
var paramawayValShoot = req.param('awayValShoot');
var paramawayTotalpass = req.param('awayTotalpass');
var paramawayValpass = req.param('awayValpass');
var paramawayOffside = req.param('awayOffside');
var paramawayCornerkick = req.param('awayCornerkick');
var paramawayFoul = req.param('awayFoul');

//image들 빠짐
if (database) {
    addStat(database, paramid, paramround, paramgroup, paramhomeName, paramhomeScore, 
            paramhomeTotalShoot, paramhomeValShoot, paramhomeTotalpass,paramhomeValpass, 
            paramhomeOffside, paramhomeCornerkick,paramhomeFoul, paramawayName,
            paramawayScore, paramawayTotalShoot, paramawayValShoot,paramawayTotalpass,
            paramawayValpass, paramawayOffside, paramawayCornerkick, paramawayFoul,
            function(err, result) {
        if (err) {throw err;}

        if (result) {
            console.dir(result);

            res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type':'text/html;charset=utf8'});

            // 뷰 템플레이트를 이용하여 렌더링한 후 전송
            var context = {title:'사용자 추가 성공'};
            req.app.render('addstat', context, function(err, html) {
                if (err) {throw err;}

                console.log("rendered : " + html);

                res.end(html);
            });

        } else {
            res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type':'text/html;charset=utf8'});
            res.write('<h2>경기 정보 추가  실패</h2>');
            res.end();
        }
    });
} else {
    res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type':'text/html;charset=utf8'});
    res.write('<h2>데이터베이스 연결 실패</h2>');
    res.end();
}};
```

// ==== error message ==== //

```
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:38:20
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:39:23
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:40:23
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:43:26
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:44:27
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:45:32
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:46:30
Fri, 28 Oct 2016 07:49:36 GMT express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead at routes\user.js:47:31
```

Then, I've changed req.param with req.body.
But, this server said to me '

> req.body is not defined

'

Can i add some other lines?
I think it's a problem about parsing. 
Could you let me know.Thanks.

Comment: To use `req.body` you need to have `body-parser` middleware

Comment: As @VsevolodGoloviznin said, you have to add the following : `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());`